# Flow chart Latex ! Positioning of two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, flow-charts

I need to split the two boxes N9 and N10 below N8 and side by side to each other. Help appreciated

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{io} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]

\node  [startstop] (start) {N1};
\node  [io, below of=start] (b2) {N2};
\node  [io, below of=b2](b3) {N3};
\node  [io, below of=b3, yshift=-0.5cm] (b4) {N5};
\node [io, below of=b4, yshift=-0.5cm](b5)  {N6};
\node (b6) [io, below of=b5, yshift=-0.5cm] {N7};
\node (b7) [io, below of=b6, yshift=-2.5] {N8};
\node (b8) [io,  below of=b7, xshift=-0.5] {N9};
\node (b9) [startstop, below of=b8] {N10};

\path [line] (start) -- (b2);
\path [line] (b2) -- (b3);
\path [line] (b3) -- (b4);
\path [line] (b4) -- (b5);
\path [line] (b5) -- (b6);
\path [line] (b6) -- (b7);
\path [line] (b7) -- (b8);
\path [line] (b8) -- (b9);
\path [line] (b9.east) node [anchor =south west] {} --+(3cm,0)  |-(b4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\caption[MD algorithm]{DFT algorithm.}
\label{DFTalgo}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) We generally prefer full minimal examples on this site, makes it much easier to help. Please provide a fully compilable example, such that we can copy the code, and compile it without having to add anything.

Comment: No it is not, there is no documentclass, no preamble ...., I cannot copy your code into a blank file on my computer and compile it as is.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if I correctly understood what you are trying to achieve. Does this provide any help?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\centering
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{io} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]

\node  [startstop] (start) {N1};
\node  [io, below of=start] (b2) {N2};
\node  [io, below of=b2](b3) {N3};
\node  [io, below of=b3, yshift=-0.5cm] (b4) {N5};
\node [io, below of=b4, yshift=-0.5cm](b5)  {N6};
\node (b6) [io, below of=b5, yshift=-0.5cm] {N7};
\node (b7) [io, below of=b6, yshift=-2.5] {N8};
\node (b8) [io,  below of=b7, xshift=-50] {N9};
\node (b9) [startstop, below of=b7, xshift=50] {N10};

\path [line] (start) -- (b2);
\path [line] (b2) -- (b3);
\path [line] (b3) -- (b4);
\path [line] (b4) -- (b5);
\path [line] (b5) -- (b6);
\path [line] (b6) -- (b7);
\path [line] (b7) -- (b8);
\path [line] (b7) -- (b9);
\path [line] (b9.east) node [anchor =south west] {} --+(1cm,0)  |-(b4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: N9 and N10 side by side]